# Javascript & Listbox Item Removal

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox

I've got a simple aspx page with a listbox, textbox and a button. The listbox is loaded at the page_load event with 40 or so items.

The button fires off the following javascript, which is supposed to remove any listbox item which does not contain the value typed by the user in the textbox. Basically, it's supposed to be a search tool.

Problem is, it only removes roughly half of the items it should. I have to click the button like 4 times to finally get the results I should have gotten on the first click. Here's the function:

```
function Search()
{
var strSearch = document.getElementById("<%= txtSearch.clientID %>").value;
var lstRsns = document.getElementById("<%= lstReasons.clientID %>");
var Temp;
var i;

for(i=0;i<lstRsns.options.length;i++)
    {
    Temp = lstRsns.options[i].text.toUpperCase();
    if (Temp.indexOf(strSearch.toUpperCase()) == -1)
        {
        lstRsns.remove(i);
        }            
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? This seems like it should work.

Thanks for any/all advice,

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list keeps shortening as you remove the elements.. just do `lstRsns.remove(0);` in the loop until you hit the one you're looking for and after that `lstRsns.remove(1);`.

Comment: Thanks for that -- only problem was there can be more than one match in the results. So I just put "i = i - 1" underneath the lstRsns.remove(i); code. Couldn't have figured that one out, Thanks!!!